# autofs does not prompt for password when needed

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to setup an automount point using autofs to mount a samba fileshare. I am using the following syntax in my auto.misc file

```
mydir    -fstype=cifs,rw,user=myusername ://server.domain/path/to/mount
```

The problem is that it is denying me with NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD (seen in /var/log/messages with -verbose turned on). It works if I add my password to the mount options using 'password=secretPass123'. I don't want the password to be stored on disk, so I would like it to prompt me for the password. When I mount it manually using "mount" if I leave out the password option, it does prompt me for the password. How do I get autofs to do the same?

I am using CentOS 6.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can have `autofs` prompt you for a password. You typically have to store it in a credentials file and reference it in automount file. This is how I've dealt with it in the past.

#### Example

```
share1     -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,netbiosname=${HOST},credentials=/etc/credentials.txt ://winserver/share1
```

This file is then locked down like so:

```
$ ls -l /etc/credentials.txt 
-rw-------. 1 root root 54 Jun 14 12:29 /etc/credentials.txt
```

containing this:

```
username=somdom\user1
password=secret123!
```

It's not ideal but is the best you can get with `autofs`. The other approach is to defer mounting to the users themselves and let them do it on demand using `gvfs`.

You can also use `pam_mount` which I cover in detail in this U&L Q&A titled: [Proper way to mount samba share](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82194/proper-way-to-mount-samba-share/82195#82195).

#### References

- [How to use my login password to do two things](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137831/how-to-use-my-login-password-to-do-two-things/137852#137852)
- [Proper way to mount samba share](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82194/proper-way-to-mount-samba-share/82195#82195)

Comment: I suppose you could make `credentials.txt` a named pipe and run a password prompting program to feed the pipe.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. I was hoping that there was some way to have `autofs` ask for a password. If I don't get a different answer soon, then I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: There is no support in autofs for it to ask for a password while mounting a share.